# VBA: Disable a macro in a source workbook

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

How can I disable the a macro in the "Source worksheet"?

```
With ThisWorkbook                                 ' enable this workbook
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Flow_table"                ' add worksheet to be used here
    Sheets.Add.Name = "TP_loc"                    ' add worksheet to be used here
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value    'get the location of the source
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = TextBox2.Value


    Set Source = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Value)
    Set Source_flow = Source.Worksheets(TextBox2.Value).Columns("A:L")
    Set target_flow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flow_table").Columns("A:L")

    ' **Insert a code here that will disable the MACRO of Source which is the source workbook**

    Source_flow.Copy Destination:=target_flow     ' copy source worksheet
    Source.Close False

End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to prevent an event procedure from running. You can stop those from firing by using:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and then resetting when you're done:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this one. :) @ThunderFrame

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Thomas Inzina

Comment: Hi @ThunderFrame, I tried this but the macro from the source workbook is still conflicting with my macro.

Comment: What is the source macro? An event procedure, or a user-defined function in a worksheet?

Comment: I am new in VBA so here is what I want to do, Copy a sheet from a different workbook (in this case its "Source"). Source have multiple macros.  it can be an event procedure an a user defined function.